# Button not working - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, browser

I found there is button compatibility on different browser(s). It was only working in Internet Explorer and get no response if i click the button in any other browsers ( like chrome, Firefox)

Below error was shown from Chrome console, 
"  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
-doQuery
-onclick"

Here is the code :

```js
function doQuery(){
 var Key = document.getElementById('searchObj.Key').value;
 }
```

```html
<input type="text" name="searchObj.Key" maxlength="6" size="12" value="" class="textbox">


<input type="button" class="btn_c" name="btnf8" value="Go" onclick="doQuery()">
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: As the name suggests, the `getElementById()` method gets the element by the `id` attribute, not the `name` attribute. `searchObj.Key` is the **name** of your input.

Comment: You don't seem to have an element with `id` of `'searchObj.Key'`.

Comment: Working alternative is `document.getElementsByName("searchObj.Key")[0].value`

Comment: @mplungjan Assuming, of course, that this `input` is the first occurrence on the page with `searchObj.Key` as its name.

Comment: I'm personally really excited by the fact that this works in MSIE (thumbs up)

Comment: @George of course, but that is the same as returned by getElementById in browsers that overload this method to get by name too

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using the dot notation for named elements "...." or for id values "..." (I think also that an id attribute value with a . or other special character in it does not validate.)

```
document.forms[0].searchObj.Key.value;
```

returns undefined

```
document.forms[0]["searchObj.Key"].value;
```

Comment: More a comment than an answer, no?